# How do I know whether the command/apple key is pressed

Tags: jquery

In my JQuery code, I have something like:

```
onKeyDown(event)
{
    if (event.ctrlKey) ...
}
```

However, on a Mac, I want to know whether the command/key (not control) key is pressed.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery key code for command key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3834175/jquery-key-code-for-command-key)