# What's the theory behind jQuery keypress, keydown, keyup black magic (on Macs)?

Tags: jquery, macos, keypress, keydown, keyup

I am confused about the various behaviors of *keypress*, *keydown*, and *keyup*. It seems that I have missed an important piece of documentation, one that explains the subtleties and nuances of this trio. Could someone help me to figure out which document I need to read in order to more effectively use these events? In case you want details, see below.

@o.v.: you asked me to show some code, but it's not really a specific problem in the code that I'm trying to solve. I'm trying to get a handle on the behaviors of these event handlers and asking someone who understands them to point me to a good piece of documentation.

I use jQuery to build an input form and insert it into my document. It works just fine, mostly. I want the form to respond to the keyboard like most other input forms I see out there: the <kbd>esc</kbd> key should dismiss the form the same as clicking the cancel button, and because the form has a `<textarea>` on it, <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd> should be the same as clicking the *OK* button. It seems simple enough to use the *keypress* event. The problem is that Chrome doesn't call my *keypress* handler for the <kbd>esc</kbd> key or <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd>. It fires for <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd> and <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd> and for alphanumerics, but not <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd>.

So I'll use *keyup* instead. I get *keyup* for <kbd>esc</kbd>, and *keyup* for <kbd>cmd</kbd>, and *keyup* for <kbd>enter</kbd>, great. But I don't get *keyup* for the <kbd>enter</kbd> key while I'm holding down <kbd>cmd</kbd>.

Third time's the charm, you might think *keydown* seems to work, but with *keydown*, you get repeat keys. I know, all you have to do is unbind the handler the first time you're called, but it just seems weird that the three different event types would behave so differently. Why is this? Is there an obvious document out there that I obviously haven't read?

Comment: "Not a real question"? I had the same doubt about the trio and had no idea I had an "unreal" question. Well, at least, now I have a better idea what behaviors to look for next time I want to (not) vote for a candidate.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

**[Keypress](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/):**

---

> The keypress event is sent to an element when the browser registers
>   keyboard input. This is similar to the keydown event, **except in the
>   case of key repeats**. If the user presses and holds a key, a keydown
>   event is **triggered once**, but **separate keypress events are triggered
>   for each inserted character**. In addition, **modifier keys** (such as
>   Shift) trigger keydown events but **not keypress events**.

**[Keydown](http://api.jquery.com/keydown/):**

---

> The keydown event is sent to an element when the user **first presses a
>   key on the keyboard**. It can be attached to any element, but the event
>   is only sent to the element that **has the focus**. Focusable elements can
>   **vary between browsers**, but form elements can always get focus so are
>   reasonable candidates for this event type.

**[Keyup](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/):**

---

> The keyup event is sent to an element when the user **releases a key on
>   the keyboard**. It can be attached to any element, but the event is only
>   sent to the element that **has the focus**. Focusable elements can vary
>   between browsers, but form elements can always get focus so are
>   reasonable candidates for this event type.

Also, this is a handy piece of information that is usually glossed over:

---

> If key presses anywhere need to be caught (for example, to implement
>   global shortcut keys on a page), it is useful to attach this behavior
>   to the **document object**. Because of event bubbling, all key presses
>   will make their way up the DOM to the document object unless
>   explicitly stopped.
>
> To determine which character was entered, examine the event object
>   that is passed to the handler function. While **browsers use differing
>   properties to store this information**, jQuery normalizes the **.which**
>   property so you can **reliably use it to retrieve the character code**.
>
> **Note that keydown and keyup provide a code indicating which key is
>   pressed, while keypress indicates which character was entered.** For
>   example, a lowercase "a" will be reported as 65 by keydown and keyup,
>   but as 97 by keypress. An uppercase "A" is reported as 65 by all
>   events. Because of this distinction, **when catching special keystrokes
>   such as arrow keys, .keydown() or .keyup() is a better choice.**

More information regarding the `cmd` key on MACs: [jQuery key code for command key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3834175/jquery-key-code-for-command-key)

Comment: Also one can go over this excellent article to understand clearly http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html

Answer (score 5):

[This article](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/keys.html) is a good resource explaining the differences between `keyup`, `keydown` and `keypress`.

The short answer is there is no easy way to handle them other than to account for the different browsers.

The way I personally handle it in a [Bootstrap plugin I wrote](https://github.com/tcrosen/twitter-bootstrap-typeahead/tree/2.0) is by creating a custom method to check which event is supported.  Coincidentally a very similar method showed up in the official Bootstrap version a little while later :P

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------
//
//  Check if an event is supported by the browser eg. 'keypress'
//  * This was included to handle the "exhaustive deprecation" of jQuery.browser in jQuery 1.8
//
eventSupported: function(eventName) {         
    var isSupported = (eventName in this.$element);

    if (!isSupported) {
      this.$element.setAttribute(eventName, 'return;');
      isSupported = typeof this.$element[eventName] === 'function';
    }

    return isSupported;
}
```

Later on I use it in my code to attach event handlers:

```
if (this.eventSupported('keydown')) {
  this.$element.on('keydown', $.proxy(this.keypress, this));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to remember that when validating a `KeyboardEvent` on a mac, `⌘` modifier key will *not* be picked up as `event.ctrlKey` but rather an `event.metaKey`. Further documentation is available on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/KeyboardEvent).

Without seeing any code, my bet is on this being the reason for `⌘+Enter` not being picked up.