# jQuery/Javascript function when value of text box is changed by user

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I would like to fire a function when the user changes the value of the text box. Not when they click on it (Like `onfocus`, `.focus` or `.change`) but when they edit the content from the pre-filled value.

HTML:

```
<input id="formloginpassword" type="text" name="pass" placeholder="Password" value="filled-from-backend"></input>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try [`keyup`](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/), [`keydown`](http://api.jquery.com/keydown/) or [`keypress`](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/):

```
​$("input").on("keyup", function(){
    console.log($(this).val())
});​
```

**[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ChaseWest/mB2g6/)**

Look here for more details about the 3 events: [What's the theory behind jQuery keypress, keydown, keyup black magic (on Macs)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12827408/whats-the-theory-behind-jquery-keypress-keydown-keyup-black-magic-on-macs/12827516#12827516)

Comment: `.keyup` is great, now that I think about it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with keypress no ?

```
$("#formloginpassword").keypress(function() {
   alert("Handler for .keypress() called.");
});
```

Documentation here -> [keypress](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/)