# application of keyup and keydown in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

When is the keyup event used and when is the keydown event used in JQuery? Why are these two separate events?

Comment: Read it here: http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/12/20/jquery-difference-between-keypress-and-keydown-events/

Comment: I am pretty sure the functionality is the same. Trigger event when key is pressed down, trigger event when the key is let go (keyup)

Comment: Do you know how to use google?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Keydown:** The keydown event is sent to an element when the user first presses a key on the keyboard. (when key is down)

**Keyup:** The keyup event is sent to an element when the user releases a key on the keyboard. (when key is released)

refer [What's the theory behind jQuery keypress, keydown, keyup black magic (on Macs)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12827408/whats-the-theory-behind-jquery-keypress-keydown-keyup-black-magic-on-macs)