# Overriding the default shortcuts of the browser (Ctrl+anyKey)

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am trying to override the default key shortcuts we use in browser (e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> to go to Tab1 and Tab2 respectively).
I have to do this using JavaScript. Please can anyone help me out?

I tried the below code which works fine when I use `alert()` but not working perfectly without `alert()` function.

Code:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
document.onkeydown = NavigateThrough;
function NavigateThrough (event)
{
    if (!document.getElementById) return;
    if (window.event) event = window.event;
    if (event.ctrlKey)
    {
        var link = null;
        switch (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which ? event.which : null)
        {
            case 0x31:
                //alert("hi 1 pressed");
                document.getElementById('txt').value = "Number : 1"; 
                break;
            case 0x32:
                //alert("hi 2 pressed");
                document.getElementById('txt').value = "Number : 2"
                break;
            case 0x33:
                //alert("hi 3 pressed");
                document.getElementById('txt').value = "Number : 3"
                break;
        }
    } 
}
</script>
<body >
<input type="text" id="txt">
</body>
```

Comment: As many others will tell you, this isn't a good idea. You don't want to override the settings users expect to have

Answer (score 1):

try adding event.preventDefault()?
because ctrl + 1 will reload the page and interrupt the code.

also, ctrl key is not necessarily enough for cross-platform browser.
consider jquery or event.metaKey

[jQuery key code for command key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3834175/jquery-key-code-for-command-key)

Comment: thanks for your reply. I tried adding event.preventDefault() but it doesnt work.It prevents my code from running.After pressing Ctrl+1 i donot get any result

Comment: It works in Chrome but not in IE.I have to make it work for IE.Any help will be appreciated.