# How can I detect macOS command keys in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I know macOS command keys in JavaScript.

Need to know left and right command keys. I know key codes of these both but I don't know how to separate from other keys.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery key code for command key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3834175/jquery-key-code-for-command-key)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/3834210/92701

Comment: [MAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address) refers to something very specific to do with networking. "Macintosh" or "Mac" is a trademark of Apple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could look on keydown/keyup and record when a key is pressed based on `event.keyCode`.

Or as Alexander pointed out, you can also use:

`event.metaKey` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/metaKey

[There are some libraries](https://github.com/madrobby/keymaster) which can help you out as these keys are browser dependent

Comment: @AlexanderElgin thanks for commenting, please revise my edit. +1 also for your solution which I like and I mention in my answer :)

Answer (score 3):

See the snippet below

```js
$(window).keydown(function (e){
    if (e.metaKey) {
      alert('meta key is pressed');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```