# How to trigger a shortcut with jQuery click

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to trigger a keyboard shortcut with jQuery? Example: execute the Shift Key + Space-bar.

```
$("body").on("click", function(){
  var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
  e.shiftKey = true;
  e.which = 32;   
  $("body").trigger(e);  
});
```

Comment: Try to refer to this one : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3834175/jquery-key-code-for-command-key/3834210 Hope this help :)

Answer (score 1):

Yep, you can bind to `keydown` event, and when appropriate combination is found, you could trigger desired event on the DOM.

In the snippet below, <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> triggers the button click.

```js
$("body").on("keydown", function(e){
  if(e.shiftKey && e.which == 32) {
    $("#button").click();
  }
});

function doSomething() {
  alert("Button was clicked");
}

function triggerShiftSpace() {
  var event = $.Event("keydown");
  event.shiftKey = true;
  event.which = 32;
  $("body").trigger(event);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button" onclick="doSomething()">
  Don't click me!
</button>

<button id="button" onclick="triggerShiftSpace()">
  Shift + Space
</button>
```

Comment: It is possible to do it in reserve where a button click triggers Shift + Space?

Comment: @yerrp Yup, I've updated the answer to show how you could do that. See the part in `setTimeout`.

Comment: I meant to type "reverse" as in the click button triggers Shift  + Space

Comment: Yep. I updated the answer. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: I assume it works but I can't get it to run, https://jsfiddle.net/1u8urv7p/

Shift + Space shortcut on a website scrolls the page up. My idea was to trigger the shortcut with a mouse click.

Comment: Here's the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1u8urv7p/1/. Also, on a website, you can scroll using [`.scrollTop`](https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) method.