# Return true if key is down in javascript loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add a condition inside a loop that tests if the right arrow is pressed and if it is move a div a bit to the right. However I don't know how to check for they keydown.

I'm using a code to do it but it is really long and I'm sure there is an shorter way to do it.

This is the code:

```
    <div id="char"></div>
    <script>
    setInterval(function() {

// here it should check if RIGHT (keycode 39) is down and move char 10px to the right if it is;

    }, 20);
    </script>
```

How can I check for keydown inside the loop? Btw I'm also using jQuery on the site.

Thanks

Comment: are you using any libraries like jQuery or just raw JS?

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445613/how-can-i-check-if-key-is-pressed-during-click-event-with-jquery

Comment: See my updated answer... added jQuery too if you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [jQuery and keydown](http://api.jquery.com/keydown/):

```
<div id="char"></div>
<script>
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 39){
          //do something
        $("#char").animate({'left':'+=10'}, 1);
     }
})
</script>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/zXeXt/

Comment: @Oscar, actually i think i made a mistake, it should be bound to `$(document)` (updated the fiddle)

Answer (score 4):

Here ya go in raw JS you'd do something like this (press Preview then hold down `w`):

http://jsbin.com/odalo3/edit

```
var isPressed = false;

var keydown = function(e){ 
  if(e.keyCode == 87){
    isPressed = true;
  }
}
var keyup = function(e){
    isPressed = false;
}

document.addEventListener("keydown",keydown,false);
document.addEventListener("keyup",keyup,false);

setInterval(function(){
  if(isPressed){
    document.getElementById('hello').innerHTML = document.getElementById('hello').innerHTML+', pressed';
  } 
},100)
```

UPDATE

If you are using jQuery you can change the eventListeners to:

```
$(window).keydown(function(e){
   if(e.keyCode == 87){
     isPressed = true;
   }
})
.keyup(function(e){
  isPressed = false;
})
```

And delete these lines:

```
var keydown = function(e){ 
  if(e.keyCode == 87){
    isPressed = true;
  }
}
var keyup = function(e){
    isPressed = false;
}

document.addEventListener("keydown",keydown,false);
document.addEventListener("keyup",keyup,false);
```

But it's the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Create a flag `var pressed;` and set it to true or false in keyPress event; then check it inside the loop

Comment: This sounds right to me. I don't know why it was downvoted. I gave you an upvote.

Comment: You should set it to `true` on `keydown` and to `false` on `keyup`.

Comment: The problem is that the "keypress" event by itself won't let you know when the "keyup" happens.

Comment: This whole answer is pretty vague IMO.

Comment: @Oscar - it's only vague if you don't know anything about JavaScript. Yes, it wasn't a full answer as I didn't have time at work, but I gave a very clear idea for the OP to start with, and it shouldn't have been down voted.