# Check if key was pressed when hovering over a div

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to check if a key on a keyboard was pressed when hovering a certain element (`div`) **without** using jQuery or a similar library?

Comment: Answer to your question is yes.

Comment: almost duplicated: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2445613/670377

Comment: Yes but I want to achieve this not using JQuery

Comment: You forgot to ask your implicit question "How to do this?" ;)

Comment: -1 You should have included on your question "using plain javascript"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a pure JS implementation:

```
myElement = document.getElementById('mydiv');

function keyaction(e){
    myElement.innerHTML+= String.fromCharCode(e.charCode);
}

myElement.addEventListener("mouseover",function() {
    document.addEventListener("keypress", keyaction);
});

myElement.addEventListener("mouseout",function() {
    document.removeEventListener("keypress", keyaction, false);
});
```

Here is a demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/bAV6f/1/

Type into the `div` when it is hovered.

Comment: Um, I don't think this is what the OP wanted.

Comment: The OP says: `a key on a keyboard was pressed` -- I believe you missed that part.

Comment: @Abody97 No, that's what the keydown listener does.

Comment: Oh oh oh, sorry, I misread your code :) Although binding and unbinding each time is kinda expensive, this should work. Sorry again.

Comment: @Abody97 This works perfectly fine, see the demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bAV6f/)

Comment: Yep, it surely works. I was just pointing out that binding and unbinding (using `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener`, that is) each time the mouse goes in or out is kinda expensive.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a plain JavaScript solution:

```
var yourDiv = document.getElementById("yourdiv"); //cache your div
var keyPressed = 0; //kinda-boolean flag, if it's not 0 then at least one key is pressed
document.onkeydown = function() { //when a key is "down"
    keyPressed ++; //increment the counter of "down" keys
};
document.onkeyup = function() { //when a key is "released"
    keyPressed --; //decrement the counter of "down" keys
    keyPressed = Math.max(0, keyPressed); //make sure it doesn't go negative
};
yourDiv.onmouseover = function() { //when you hover your div
    if(keyPressed !== 0) { //if a key is pressed
        //do stuff
    }
};
```

The above only fires the mouse events when the mouse **enters** your `div`. If you want it to fire if it moves inside it, use the `onmousemove` event instead:

```
yourDiv.onmousemove = function() { //when the mouse moves inside your div
    if(keyPressed !== 0) { //if a key is pressed
        //do stuff
    }
};
```

Note that you can use `addEventListener` instead of directly setting `onkeydown`, `onkeyup` and `onmousemover` -- but the concept stays the same.

Comment: +1 for not using a library :)

Comment: This doesn't register events that occur while the mouse is hovered over the div. The question is `is it possible to check if a key on a keyboard was pressed when hovering a certain element`, not `is it possible to check if the element was moused over while a key on the keyboard was pressed`

Comment: @Abody97 That is still incorrect. The event isn't supposed to be triggered by mouse movement. It is supposed to be triggered by a keypress provided that the mouse is inside the element ("hovering the element", to quote the OP).

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is yes, this is possible.

You would have to add a javascript event on hover (onmouseover) over the div that sets a keydown event on the same div.

You will have to remove the keydown event when the user stops the hover again (onmouseout).

Comment: I'm trying to achieve this in plain javascript or dojo. Is there a way

Comment: Yes this is possible in plain javascript, although it is different for several browsers. Read ie. http://seanmonstar.com/post/706917892/cross-browser-addevent-without-frameworks. I don't know dojo, but i can assure you that it also has an addevent option somewhere.

Comment: Actually. Here is a manual for dojo http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/events/

Answer (score 0):

#### Short anwser

**Yes**, is possible

#### but, how can be done if it is possible?

Well, using Jquery is pretty simple:

```
$("div#selector").mouseover(function(e) {
  if (e.ctrlKey)
    alert('You are hover selector and pressing ctrl');
  if (e.altKey)
    alert('You are hover selector and pressing alt');
  if (evt.which == 77)
    alert('You are hover selector and pressing m');
  ...
});
```

See this [list of key](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes) to know the javascript keycode associated with a character

**Edit**: I just readed your comment about not to use jQuery which should be included in the question

Answer (score -1):

You can use the jquery for this purpose

```
$("p").hover(function(){
//Your code
});
```

Or

```
$(".selector").on({
mouseenter: function () {
//stuff to do on mouseover
}, 
mouseleave: function () {
//stuff to do on mouseleave

}

});
```