# jquery unordered list multiselect with ctrl

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to create a multiselect on unordred list when clicking on on `<li>` items and holding <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key, and when clicking on `<li>` without holding the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> it just select the current item and deselect others.

```
<div class="list">
    <ul class="level0">
        <li class="level1">text1</li>
        <li class="level1">text2</li>
        <li class="level1">text3</li>
        <li class="level1">text4</li>
        <li class="level1">text5</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="level0">
        <ul class="level1">
            <li class="level2">text1</li>
            <li class="level2">text2</li>
            <li class="level2">text3</li>
            <li class="level2">text4</li>
            <li class="level2">text5</li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="level1">
            <li class="level2">text1</li>
            <li class="level2">text2</li>
            <li class="level2">text3</li>
            <li class="level2">text4</li>
            <li class="level2">text5</li>
        </ul>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Any idea to do this?

Comment: I suggest - http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445613/how-can-i-check-if-key-is-pressed-during-click-event-with-jquery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use jquery to check if a modifier key was pressed when listening to an event. You can check for the following keys on the event object passed to the handler:

```
altKey - alt/option key
ctrlKey - control key
shiftKey - shift key
metaKey - control key on PCs, control and/or command key on Macs
```

Example:

```
var lis = $('.list li').click(function(e){
    if(!e.ctrlKey) {
        // Ctrl not pressed, clear previous selections
         lis.removeClass("selected");      
    }
    $(this).addClass("selected");    
});
```

Working fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/AM2Sk/

Comment: how to prevent Mac from open the list in a new window when use cmd?