# Onclick with Ctrl hold duplicate one li element to another list

Tags: javascript, html, list, dom, space-efficiency

So basically what I need to do, is when I click on one UL list item, while holding Ctrl it needs to duplicate and that copy needs to go to another list, so far I've got to where only when I click on something it goes to another list with no Ctrl  which is also mandatory for this homework.
I'll upload script what I have so far:

```
var usersA = document.getElementById("users-a");
var usersB = document.getElementById("users-b");

var onclickA;
var onclickB = function() {
        usersA.appendChild(this);
        this.onclick = onclickA;
        return false;
    };
onclickA = function() {
        usersB.appendChild(this);
        this.onclick = onclickB;
        return false;
    };

for (var i=0; i < usersA.getElementsByTagName("li").length; i++)
    usersA.getElementsByTagName("li")[i].onclick = onclickA;
for (var i=0; i < usersB.getElementsByTagName("li").length; i++)      
    usersB.getElementsByTagName("li")[i].onclick = onclickB;
```

Any suggestions on how to do it with the least amount of code as possible? I mean do I need to create another event for that, I am lost, Thanks for any help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i check if key is pressed during click event with jquery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445613/how-can-i-check-if-key-is-pressed-during-click-event-with-jquery)

Comment: I don't need jquery, i need javascript

Comment: Well then rewrite it accordingly …

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To what I understand like you said. If the `ctrl` key is been pressed down and the `li` element is clicked. Basically there is not such way to detect if the `ctrl` key is been held down. But this trick below will return true on keydown and false on keyup. Therefore when the `ctrl` key is held down it is always true until it is been released

```
var keys = {};
onkeydown = onkeyup = function(e){
    e = e || event;
    keys[e.keyCode] = e.type == 'keydown';
    if(keys[17] == true){
        //the ctrl key is held down, so run your code here
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, You are correct, is there is any way to combine those two codes to one?

Comment: Yes you can. just copy all your code and paste it where I commented `//the ctrl key is held down, so run your code here`. and it will work perfect.

Please don't forget to upvote my answer