# JavaScript function embedded in href tag, cannot be opened in new tab

Tags: javascript, html, href

I have a javascript function `load_url(url)` that validates url and open relevant page.

```
function load_url(url) {

    // Performing some validation 
    // ...
    // ...

    window.location.assign(validatedUrl);
}
```

I have embedded `load_url(url)` in each href to open validated page. Like this

```
href="JavaScript:load_url('index.php?data=CreateBill')"
```

This function works normally when directly clicked but open `blank page` when user try to open it in new tab.

> about:blank#blocked

Is there any way to open javascript function (embedded in href) to new tab?

Comment: u could try to redirect to a .php script, grab the new url via $get, and redirect there. of course this is not plain javascript, so maybe you want to wait a little longer for better answeres

Comment: I would check if user was holding ctrl key, and then open new tab for him with validated address. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445613/how-can-i-check-if-a-key-is-pressed-during-the-click-event-with-jquery

Comment: @Kudlas What if the user pressed middle mouse button?

Comment: I guess you have to check that too.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392442/detect-middle-button-click-scroll-button-with-jquery